# At a wall socket, is using thin wires at ground pin dangerous?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, safety, socket

I paid a hardware shop owner to modify my wall light switch to socket for my washing machine in bathroom. The power in my area right now is 3 phase 220V AC.
At first it is a switch.
[image]
Then we modified it to a switch with socket like this.
[image]
He connected the two power pin between wall and socket with original thick wire from wall. But when connecting ground, thick wire ran out,so he cut and use the several wires from my electrical brake of my broken electrical scooter. But, it is probably a DC 3.6,5, or 12 V wire, or at worst case it may just be a signal wire not supposed to transmit power. Isn't it dangerous even he used several wires in parallel? Although he kept promising it is safe, I am not sure. According to my deduction, ground is used when something goes wrong like close circuit, insulation failure, electrical shock, thunder, or releasing accumulated statistic electricity. Does it  mean normally it is safe and works fine, and indeed my washing machine works fine, but dangerous at unexpected condition? If needed, I can take and post the picture tonight if it helps.

Furthermore,
I paid another hardware shop owner to fix it yesterday. I found acturally ground and neutral wires are small and parallel. Not only ground as I remember before.
This is the installation after fix. Extension power wire is 2.5mm of copper the same as wire inside wall, and the wire to light is smaller maybe 2.0 or 1.5mm
[image]

Before fix, the parallel small wire is like this. Insulation is about 1mm and copper is about 0.5mm.
[image]

Comment: Do you know what size the grounding wire that was used actually is, in mm2? Because there are two different problems here -- the size of the copper in the wire, and the size/type of the insulation *around* that copper....

Comment: Using several wires in parallel is dangerous.  Get the right thing and fit it when able.

Comment: I will check the wire size today, thank you.

Comment: A picture of your actual installation with the power switched off at the circuit breaker, the cover plate removed and the receptacle/switch carefully removed (do _not_ disconnect the wiring!!) would be very helpful, too.

Comment: Your "update" sounds like it should be an answer. Self-answering a question is perfectly acceptable and is actually expected. Providing an answer in the "question" box actually makes it harder for people to find questions that have been properly answered. Please edit the answer out of your question, paste the text & pictures into an Answer, then give click the check-mark so others know it's been answered. TBH, though, it looks like one of those splices has simply been electrical taped together and that's generally a bad sign. There should be some sort of insulated connector there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reminding @FreeMan. In fact I don't ask for how to fix it. I ask for is wiring with thin wire in parallel dangerous, these two is indeed similar and easy to confuse, and which I am afraid I am not qualified to answer, because I really don't know based on my basic home electricity knowledge. My fixing logic is that since I am not sure if it is dangerous or not, the safe way is to assume it is dangerous and just replace it no matter what.  But, still thank you very much for your encouraging.

Comment: For the insulation part, would you please kindly provide a link of the insulation connector? I have never see one in my life, and I have only seen this kind of black electrical type used on construction site or home socket wiring.  Thank you.

Comment: Search for "wire nut" - that will give you a general idea of what I'm talking about. **HOWEVER**, it seems you're not in the US, so the specific type of connectors will be dependent on exactly where you live. While this _is_ a DIY site and we encourage people to learn to DIY, electricity can burn down your house and/or kill you. This may be a time for you to hire a professional for safety reasons. Watch over his shoulder to see what he's doing and start your education there. When he's done, look at his work, the do some reading on  your local electrical code (con't...)

Comment: ... to learn how things should be done in _your_ country. For example, in the US, as a homeowner, I'm allowed to do electrical work on my own house, but I am required to follow my state's electrical code in the work I do. I am _not_ allowed to do any electrical work on anyone else's house unless I'm a _state licensed_ electrician. It sounds like you've asked a local store owner to do the work for you - that may be legal where you live, but it wouldn't be here in the US. For your safety, and that of those who live around you - seriously consider hiring a professional for this work!